# Inner join 3 tables in JPA with where clause

Tags: jpa, inner-join, where-clause, many-to-one

I'm struggling to make a query that inner join 3 tables and have a where clause. It's like my where doesn't exist.

Here are my entities:

`CarModel` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARMODEL")
public class CarModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "carModel")
    private List<MyCars> myCars;
```

`MyCars` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MYCARS")
public class MyCars implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name = "CarModel_id")
    private CarModel carModel= new CarModel();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user = new User();
```

User entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<MyCars> myCars;
```

Here is the graphical representation of these three entities:

[image: Represenation of the entities]

And here is one of the queries i have tried:

```
public List<CarModel> findMyCarsByUserId(long IdUser)
{
    String requete = "SELECT DISTINCT cm\n" +
    "FROM MyCars ms\n" +
    " INNER JOIN CarModel cm INNER JOIN User u where u.id=2";

    Query query = em.createQuery(requete);
    //query.setParameter("iduser", IdUser);
    List<CarModel> cars = null;
    cars = (List<CarModel>) query.getResultList();  
    return cars;
}
```

So here I'm trying to get all the `ModeleVehicule` for a given `user_id`. But I keep having all the `ModeleVehicule` of the table, despite the where clause.

I have a mysql query working for what I want:

```
SELECT cm.marque,cm.modele, cm.motorisation, cm.anneeModele, cm.puissance 
  FROM carmodel cm
 INNER JOIN mycars ms ON cm.ID = ms.ModeleVehicule_id
 INNER JOIN user u ON ms.user_id = u.ID
 WHERE ms.user_id = 1
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/tutorial/relationships/relationships.html @ManyToMany() and @JoinTable() perhaps? MyCars entity - has a different name too in your diagram

Comment: thx for that i will look at it, for the different name in my diagram, it's because i have translated my code in english, but not the diagram ^^'